# Basic Gazebo Tutorial Crashes - Building Your Own Robot

Tags: gazebo

I'm very new to Gazebo simulation and was just running through the [first basic tutorial](https://gazebosim.org/docs/harmonic/building_robot) after installing Gazebo Harmonic via the [binary installation for Ubuntu 22.04](https://gazebosim.org/docs/harmonic/install_ubuntu)

As I was going through step-by-step, I noticed that the vehicle wasn't appearing, so I copied the code from [here](https://github.com/gazebosim/docs/blob/master/harmonic/tutorials/building_robot/building_robot.sdf) into a file and the simulator wouldn't run at all.

This is obviously the most trivial setup, and I'm curious what exactly I'm missing.

**Steps to reproduce**

In your project folder, copy the following contents into a file named `build_robot.sdf`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.8">
    <world name="car_world">
        <physics name="1ms" type="ignored">
            <max_step_size>0.001</max_step_size>
            <real_time_factor>1.0</real_time_factor>
        </physics>
        <plugin
            filename="gz-sim-physics-system"
            name="gz::sim::systems::Physics">
        </plugin>
        <plugin
            filename="gz-sim-user-commands-system"
            name="gz::sim::systems::UserCommands">
        </plugin>
        <plugin
            filename="gz-sim-scene-broadcaster-system"
            name="gz::sim::systems::SceneBroadcaster">
        </plugin>

        <light type="directional" name="sun">
            <cast_shadows>true</cast_shadows>
            <pose>0 0 10 0 0 0</pose>
            <diffuse>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</diffuse>
            <specular>0.2 0.2 0.2 1</specular>
            <attenuation>
                <range>1000</range>
                <constant>0.9</constant>
                <linear>0.01</linear>
                <quadratic>0.001</quadratic>
            </attenuation>
            <direction>-0.5 0.1 -0.9</direction>
        </light>

        <model name="ground_plane">
            <static>true</static>
            <link name="link">
                <collision name="collision">
                <geometry>
                    <plane>
                    <normal>0 0 1</normal>
                    </plane>
                </geometry>
                </collision>
                <visual name="visual">
                <geometry>
                    <plane>
                    <normal>0 0 1</normal>
                    <size>100 100</size>
                    </plane>
                </geometry>
                <material>
                    <ambient>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</ambient>
                    <diffuse>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</diffuse>
                    <specular>0.8 0.8 0.8 1</specular>
                </material>
                </visual>
            </link>
        </model>

        <model name='vehicle_blue' canonical_link='chassis'>
            <pose relative_to='world'>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>   <!--the pose is relative to the world by default-->

            <!--chassis-->
            <link name='chassis'>
                <pose relative_to='__model__'>0.5 0 0.4 0 0 0</pose>
                <inertial> <!--inertial properties of the link mass, inertia matix-->
                    <mass>1.14395</mass>
                    <inertia>
                        <ixx>0.095329</ixx>
                        <ixy>0</ixy>
                        <ixz>0</ixz>
                        <iyy>0.381317</iyy>
                        <iyz>0</iyz>
                        <izz>0.476646</izz>
                    </inertia>
                </inertial>
                <visual name='visual'>
                    <geometry>
                        <box>
                            <size>2.0 1.0 0.5</size>
                        </box>
                    </geometry>
                    <!--Color of the link-->
                    <material>
                        <ambient>0.0 0.0 1.0 1</ambient>
                        <diffuse>0.0 0.0 1.0 1</diffuse>
                        <specular>0.0 0.0 1.0 1</specular>
                    </material>
                </visual>
                <collision name='collision'>
                    <geometry>
                        <box>
                            <size>2.0 1.0 0.5</size>
                        </box>
                    </geometry>
                </collision>
            </link>

            <!--Left wheel-->
            <link name='left_wheel'>
                <pose relative_to="chassis">-0.5 0.6 0 -1.5707 0 0</pose> <!--angles are in radian-->
                <inertial>
                    <mass>1</mass>
                    <inertia>
                        <ixx>0.043333</ixx>
                        <ixy>0</ixy>
                        <ixz>0</ixz>
                        <iyy>0.043333</iyy>
                        <iyz>0</iyz>
                        <izz>0.08</izz>
                    </inertia>
                </inertial>
                <visual name='visual'>
                    <geometry>
                        <cylinder>
                            <radius>0.4</radius>
                            <length>0.2</length>
                        </cylinder>
                    </geometry>
                    <material>
                        <ambient>1.0 0.0 0.0 1</ambient>
                        <diffuse>1.0 0.0 0.0 1</diffuse>
                        <specular>1.0 0.0 0.0 1</specular>
                    </material>
                </visual>
                <collision name='collision'>
                    <geometry>
                        <cylinder>
                            <radius>0.4</radius>
                            <length>0.2</length>
                        </cylinder>
                    </geometry>
                </collision>
            </link>

            <!--The same as left wheel but with different position-->
            <link name='right_wheel'>
                <pose relative_to="chassis">-0.5 -0.6 0 -1.5707 0 0</pose> <!--angles are in radian-->
                <inertial>
                    <mass>1</mass>
                    <inertia>
                        <ixx>0.043333</ixx>
                        <ixy>0</ixy>
                        <ixz>0</ixz>
                        <iyy>0.043333</iyy>
                        <iyz>0</iyz>
                        <izz>0.08</izz>
                    </inertia>
                </inertial>
                <visual name='visual'>
                    <geometry>
                        <cylinder>
                            <radius>0.4</radius>
                            <length>0.2</length>
                        </cylinder>
                    </geometry>
                    <material>
                        <ambient>1.0 0.0 0.0 1</ambient>
                        <diffuse>1.0 0.0 0.0 1</diffuse>
                        <specular>1.0 0.0 0.0 1</specular>
                    </material>
                </visual>
                <collision name='collision'>
                    <geometry>
                        <cylinder>
                            <radius>0.4</radius>
                            <length>0.2</length>
                        </cylinder>
                    </geometry>
                </collision>
            </link>

            <!--arbitrary frame-->
            <frame name="caster_frame" attached_to='chassis'>
                <pose>0.8 0 -0.2 0 0 0</pose>
            </frame>

            <!--caster wheel-->
            <link name='caster'>
                <pose relative_to='caster_frame'/>
                <inertial>
                    <mass>1</mass>
                    <inertia>
                        <ixx>0.016</ixx>
                        <ixy>0</ixy>
                        <ixz>0</ixz>
                        <iyy>0.016</iyy>
                        <iyz>0</iyz>
                        <izz>0.016</izz>
                    </inertia>
                </inertial>
                <visual name='visual'>
                    <geometry>
                        <sphere>
                            <radius>0.2</radius>
                        </sphere>
                    </geometry>
                    <material>
                        <ambient>0.0 1 0.0 1</ambient>
                        <diffuse>0.0 1 0.0 1</diffuse>
                        <specular>0.0 1 0.0 1</specular>
                    </material>
                </visual>
                <collision name='collision'>
                    <geometry>
                        <sphere>
                            <radius>0.2</radius>
                        </sphere>
                    </geometry>
                </collision>
            </link>

            <!--left wheel joint-->
            <joint name='left_wheel_joint' type='revolute'>
                <pose relative_to='left_wheel'/>
                <parent>chassis</parent>
                <child>left_wheel</child>
                <axis>
                    <xyz expressed_in='__model__'>0 1 0</xyz> <!--can be descired to any frame or even arbitrary frames-->
                    <limit>
                        <lower>-1.79769e+308</lower>    <!--negative infinity-->
                        <upper>1.79769e+308</upper>     <!--positive infinity-->
                    </limit>
                </axis>
            </joint>

            <!--right wheel joint-->
            <joint name='right_wheel_joint' type='revolute'>
                <pose relative_to='right_wheel'/>
                <parent>chassis</parent>
                <child>right_wheel</child>
                <axis>
                    <xyz expressed_in='__model__'>0 1 0</xyz>
                    <limit>
                        <lower>-1.79769e+308</lower>    <!--negative infinity-->
                        <upper>1.79769e+308</upper>     <!--positive infinity-->
                    </limit>
                </axis>
            </joint>

            <!--caster wheel joint--> <!--pose defult value is the child-->
            <joint name='caster_wheel' type='ball'>
                <parent>chassis</parent>
                <child>caster</child>
            </joint>
        </model>
    </world>
</sdf>
```

Then run

```bash
gz sim -v2 building_robot.sdf
```

I get the following output

```
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
/nix/store/bhynrw9xbvgwhs0xc61wm7c5iwhbph4j-dconf-0.40.0-lib/lib/gio/modules/libdconfsettings.so: undefined symbol: g_assertion_message_cmpint
Failed to load module: /nix/store/bhynrw9xbvgwhs0xc61wm7c5iwhbph4j-dconf-0.40.0-lib/lib/gio/modules/libdconfsettings.so
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:904] [QT] file::/EntityContextMenuPlugin/EntityContextMenuPlugin.qml:52:3: QML RenderWindowOverlay: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead.
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:904] [QT] file::/EntityContextMenuPlugin/EntityContextMenuPlugin.qml:67:3: QML EntityContextMenu: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead.
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:904] [QT] file::/EntityContextMenuPlugin/EntityContextMenuPlugin.qml:52:3: QML RenderWindowOverlay: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead.
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:904] [QT] file::/EntityContextMenuPlugin/EntityContextMenuPlugin.qml:67:3: QML EntityContextMenu: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead.
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:904] [QT] file::/EntityContextMenuPlugin/EntityContextMenuPlugin.qml:52:3: QML RenderWindowOverlay: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead.
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:904] [QT] file::/EntityContextMenuPlugin/EntityContextMenuPlugin.qml:67:3: QML EntityContextMenu: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead.
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:904] [QT] file::/EntityContextMenuPlugin/EntityContextMenuPlugin.qml:52:3: QML RenderWindowOverlay: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead.
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:904] [QT] file::/EntityContextMenuPlugin/EntityContextMenuPlugin.qml:67:3: QML EntityContextMenu: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead.
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:904] [QT] file::/EntityContextMenuPlugin/EntityContextMenuPlugin.qml:52:3: QML RenderWindowOverlay: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead.
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:904] [QT] file::/EntityContextMenuPlugin/EntityContextMenuPlugin.qml:67:3: QML EntityContextMenu: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead.
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:904] [QT] file::/EntityContextMenuPlugin/EntityContextMenuPlugin.qml:52:3: QML RenderWindowOverlay: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead.
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:904] [QT] file::/EntityContextMenuPlugin/EntityContextMenuPlugin.qml:67:3: QML EntityContextMenu: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead.
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:904] [QT] file::/EntityTree/EntityTree.qml:148:7: QML ToolButton: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead.
[GUI] [Wrn] [Component.hh:189] Trying to deserialize component with data type [N3sdf3v145WorldE], which doesn't have `operator>>`. Component will not be deserialized.
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:904] [QT] file::/WorldStats/WorldStats.qml:53:3: QML RowLayout: Binding loop detected for property "x"
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:904] [QT] file::/EntityContextMenuPlugin/EntityContextMenuPlugin.qml:52:3: QML RenderWindowOverlay: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead.
[GUI] [Wrn] [Application.cc:904] [QT] file::/EntityContextMenuPlugin/EntityContextMenuPlugin.qml:67:3: QML EntityContextMenu: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead.
[Wrn] [SimulationRunner.cc:720] Found additional publishers on /stats, using namespaced stats topic only
[Wrn] [SimulationRunner.cc:754] Found additional publishers on /clock, using namespaced clock topic only
[Wrn] [Component.hh:144] Trying to serialize component with data type [N3sdf3v145WorldE], which doesn't have `operator<<`. Component will not be serialized.
[Wrn] [Model.hh:69] Skipping serialization / deserialization for models with //pose/@relative_to attribute.
[GUI] [Wrn] [Model.hh:98] Unable to deserialize sdf::Model
[GUI] [Err] [BaseStorage.hh:975] Another item already exists with name: sun
Stack trace (most recent call last) in thread 124907:
#23   Object "[0xffffffffffffffff]", at 0xffffffffffffffff, in 
#22   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", at 0x7fc0eeb2665f, in 
#21   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", at 0x7fc0eea94ac2, in 
#20   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5", at 0x7fc0e8accca0, in 
#19   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5", at 0x7fc0e8acbaf1, in QThread::exec()
#18   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5", at 0x7fc0e8cb875a, in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>)
#17   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5", at 0x7fc0e8d130b7, in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>)
#16   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0", at 0x7fc0e7b193e2, in g_main_context_iteration
#15   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0", at 0x7fc0e7b71257, in 
#14   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0", at 0x7fc0e7b1bd3a, in g_main_context_dispatch
#13   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5", at 0x7fc0e8d13a66, in 
#12   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5", at 0x7fc0e8cbcf26, in QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents(QObject*, int, QThreadData*)
#11   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5", at 0x7fc0e8cb9e39, in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*)
#10   Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5", at 0x7fc0e836c712, in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*)
#9    Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5", at 0x7fc0e8ce741d, in QObject::event(QEvent*)
#8    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gz-gui-8/plugins/libMinimalScene.so", at 0x7fc0c00b0968, in gz::gui::plugins::RenderThread::RenderNext(gz::gui::plugins::RenderSync*)
#7    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gz-gui-8/plugins/libMinimalScene.so", at 0x7fc0c00c32d8, in gz::gui::plugins::RenderThreadRhiOpenGL::RenderNext(gz::gui::plugins::RenderSync*)
#6    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gz-gui-8/plugins/libMinimalScene.so", at 0x7fc0c00b4f5f, in gz::gui::plugins::GzRenderer::Render(gz::gui::plugins::RenderSync*, gz::gui::plugins::RenderThreadRhi&)
#5    Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5", at 0x7fc0e8cb9e39, in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*)
#4    Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5", at 0x7fc0e836c701, in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*)
#3    Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5", at 0x7fc0e8cb9b99, in QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendThroughObjectEventFilters(QObject*, QEvent*)
#2    Object "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gz-sim-8/plugins/gui/libGzSceneManager.so", at 0x7fc0b3ee8f40, in gz::sim::v8::GzSceneManager::eventFilter(QObject*, QEvent*)
#1    Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgz-sim8-rendering.so.8", at 0x7fc0b06c4dfc, in gz::sim::v8::RenderUtil::Update()
#0    Object "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgz-sim8-rendering.so.8", at 0x7fc0b070fd11, in gz::sim::v8::SceneManager::CreateLight(unsigned long, sdf::v14::Light const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned long)
Segmentation fault (Address not mapped to object [(nil)])
```

**System & install information**

```bash
❯ gz sim --version             
Gazebo Sim, version 8.0.0
Copyright (C) 2018 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2.0 License.
```

```bash
❯ uname -a
Linux ----- 6.2.0-39-generic #40~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Nov 16 10:53:04 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```bash
❯ cat /etc/lsb-release     
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS"
```

Thank you kindly for your assistance.

**edit:**

### Solution:

After further investigation, I decided that I may have better luck with an older LTS, so I downgraded to Ignition Fortress and the application worked flawlessly when running `ign gazebo building_robot.sdf`. To resolve some of the comments, I made sure there was only one instance of `sun`

```
❯ rg sun             
building_robot.sdf
21:        <light type="directional" name="sun">
```

and nothing was returned by `ps -ef | grep "gz sim"`

Comment: as the error suggests: [GUI] [Err] [BaseStorage.hh:975] Another item already exists with name: sun      |        Is there any other entity named sun in your sdf? just check once again also try changing the direction name in sdf file to other name.

Comment: Can you also check there's not another instance of Gazebo running? Try `ps -ef | grep "gz sim"`